# How to group object with arrays and show only first 3 groups and add a style to them in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object with arrays. For example: offers of services with different priorities(how important they are). I need to group these offers by priority level and only show to user first top 3 groups. Also it will be nice to give each top group a special css class(like a color).

Here what I tried to do:

```
//Object with Arrays
const data = [  {"name":"offer1", "prior":1},
                {"name":"offer2", "prior":1},
                {"name":"offer3", "prior":2},
                {"name":"offer4", "prior":2},
                {"name":"offer5", "prior":3},
                {"name":"offer5", "prior":3}];

//Sort offers by priority
  data.sort((a,b) => Number(a.prior) > Number(b.prior) ? 1 : -1);

//group offers by priority  
        this.groupOffers = window._.groupBy(this.relatedmodels.items, e => e.offer_rel_priority);
//take top3 groups
        let top1 = Object.entries(this.groupOffers).slice(0,1).map(entry => entry[1]);
        let top2 = Object.entries(this.groupOffers).slice(1,2).map(entry => entry[1]);
        let top3 = Object.entries(this.groupOffers).slice(2,3).map(entry => entry[1]);
```